# R not recognizing time component of datetime values

Tags: r, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a dataframe where one column lists a bunch of datetimes. Oddly, the data type for that column is "integer." I need to coerce the column to a proper datetime data type such as POSIXct so that I can subtract these timestamps from those in another field. However, when I try to coerce these datetime values into POSIXct, they lose the time component. When I try to do math on the datetimes without first coercing into another datatype, R acts as if the time component of the timestamp isn't there (it assumes each date has a time of midnight). What's going on and how do I fix it so that R recognizes the timestamp?

```
> dates[1]
[1] 2016-05-05T16:46:21-04:00
48 Levels: 2016-05-03T06:45:42-04:00 2016-05-03T06:45:43-04:00 ... 2016-05-05T16:50:00-04:00
> typeof(dates)
[1] "integer"
> as.POSIXct(dates[1])
[1] "2016-05-05 EDT"
> as.character(dates[1])
[1] "2016-05-05T16:46:21-04:00"
> as.POSIXct(as.character(dates[1]))
[1] "2016-05-05 EDT"
```

Comment: The `48 Levels` is a hint that R treats it as factors. If you've used `read.csv` then use `stringAsFactors=F`

Comment: You have a non-standard date-time format. R will probably need some help  `as.POSIXct("2016-05-05T16:46:21-04:00", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `as.POSIXct` with the `tz` argument to convert the timestamps with the right level of control.

If the timezones are all UTC-04:00 and that is your local timezone, you can use:

```
dates = as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz=Sys.timezone())
```

If they are all UTC-04:00 and that is not your local timezone, but you know the exact location, then you can specify the appropriate timezone from the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones):

```
dates = as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="America/Port_of_Spain")
```

Alternatively, you can use a generic GMT-4 timezone:

```
dates = as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="Etc/GMT-4")
```

[EDIT: With thanks to Roland for his comment below. I originally used `strptime`, which uses the same syntax, but returns a `POSIXlt` object.]

Comment: You can use `as.POSIXct` in the same way. It gives you a POSIXct object which is generally preferable over POSIXlt, which is what `strptime` returns-

Comment: Thank you, I have amended my answer accordingly.